# install software that comes on 3.5 inch floppies

Tags: floppy

How do I install software which comes on 3.5 inch floppies onto a laptop that does no have a floppy drive?

Comment: Just curious, is it recent software or something older?

Comment: Uh, that would definitely be... OLDER... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a USB floppy drive

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a USB floppy drive, you could use another PC to transfer the software to a flash drive, CD, or use a network connection.